# Detecting if existing serial connection is lost due to device unplugged on Windows

Tags: windows, serial-port

I'm calling Win32 ReadFile to read from a Windows serial port. If my device is unplugged, ReadFile still returns success. How can I check if the connection to the device has been lost? I could do this by sending a message and not getting a response or listening for device events  but is there any more straightforward way?

Comment: Check the DSR hardware signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serial ports are dumb in that there is no device independent way of knowing when something is or is/not plugged into the serial port. Because of this, most devices that use serial ports support some kind of communication protocol which will allow you to determine if something is connected or not.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the language, I am not certain if serial devices cause a device change event, and I do not have one at the moment to test.

However if PNP will pick it up I would try

From the WmiCode creator

```
Imports System
Imports System.Management
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Namespace WMISample

    Public Class WMIReceiveEvent

        Public Overloads Shared Function Main() As Integer

            Try

                Dim query As New WqlEventQuery( _
                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent")

                Dim watcher As New ManagementEventWatcher(query)
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for an event...")

                Dim eventObj As ManagementBaseObject = watcher.WaitForNextEvent()

                Console.WriteLine("{0} event occurred.", eventObj("__CLASS"))

                ' Cancel the event subscription
                watcher.Stop()
                Return 0

            Catch err As ManagementException

                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while trying to receive an event: " & err.Message)
            End Try
        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

From there you van further refine what was added or removed from the system.
It does little however for the fact the machine may have been booted without the device attached.

Either way I suggest in all communication protocols that proper communication error handing is essential. It is similar to the fact that you cannot guarantee that a socket has become disconnected between checking to see if connected and writing.